# background subtraction in a table

Tags: r, data.table, bioconductor

I have gene expression data as number of counts for each probe, something like this:

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- fread(
"molclass,mol.id,sample1,sample2,sample3
negative, negat1,  0, 1,   2
negative, negat2,  2, 1,   1
negative, negat3,  1, 2,   0
 endogen,  gene1, 30, 15, 10
 endogen,  gene2, 60, 30, 20
")
```

My question here is - what would be the best way to perform background subtraction, i.e. for each `sampleN` column I need to calculate background (let's say it will be the average of all values from `negative` class) and then subtract this background from each value of this column. For the moment I am using the following solution:

```
for (nm in names(mydata)[-c(1:2)]) {
  bg <- mydata[molclass=='negative', nm, with=F];
  bg <- mean(unlist(bg));
  mydata[[nm]] <- (mydata[[nm]] - bg);
}
```

but I feel there must be some "nicer" way.

P.S. I know that there are some packages that do those things, but my data correspond to the number of counts, not intensity of signal - so I can't use `limma` or similar tools designed for microarrays. Maybe some seq-data packages could help, but I am not sure because my data is not from sequencing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't use `<-` with a `data.table`. The last assignment in your loop would be better with `set`. See the help page by typing `?set` for details.

```
mycols  <- paste0('sample',1:3)
newcols <- paste0(mycols,'bk')

s       <- mydata[['molclass']] == 'negative'
mybkds  <- sapply(mycols,function(j) mean(mydata[[j]][s]) )

mydata[,(newcols):=NA]
for (j in mycols) set(mydata,j=paste0(j,'bk'),value=mydata[[j]]-mybkds[j])
```

I've only done the last step in a loop, but this is basically the same as your code (where everything is in the loop). `*apply` functions and loops are just different syntax, I've heard, and you can go with whichever you prefer.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution and especially for the explanations!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to replace the `sample` columns with the calculated values, you can use `set` (as in @Frank's post) but without creating an additional object

```
indx <- grep('^sample', names(mydata))
for(j in indx){
 set(mydata, i=NULL, j=j, value=mydata[[j]]- 
       mydata[molclass=='negative', mean(unlist(.SD)), .SDcols=j])
}
mydata
#   molclass  mol.id sample1    sample2 sample3
#1: negative  negat1      -1 -0.3333333       1
#2: negative  negat2       1 -0.3333333       0
#3: negative  negat3       0  0.6666667      -1
#4:  endogen   gene1      29 13.6666667       9
#5:  endogen   gene2      59 28.6666667      19
```

Or a variant (more efficient) as suggested by @Frank would be

```
for(j in indx){
 set(mydata, i=NULL, j=j, value=mydata[[j]]- 
    mean(mydata[[j]][mydata$molclass=='negative']))
}
```

Comment: Sure, that's actually closer to what I'd do, though the "background" object being subtracted can (should?) be computed without using square brackets and .SD -- `mean(mydata[[j]][mydata$molclass=='negative'])` --... at least that's what the knowledgeable folks usually say. Also, I guess you're overwriting the original values, which is consistent with the OP's desired output (and makes it possible to do everything in one `set` command), but maybe not the right way to go in many cases.

Comment: @Frank Yes, that is better.  I was only thinking to do that in a single `[`.  Regarding overwriting the values, yes, I was only looking at the expected result.  In my post, I did menion about that.

Comment: Fyi, the `[` in my last comment is different from the `[` in `mydata[`. The first is just subsetting a vector, while the latter calls `[.data.table`, which, for whatever reason, has some overhead, as does `.SD` inside it.

Comment: @Frank Right now, the `.SD` may be a bit slower, but I guess it will be optimized (to make it faster) in the new version.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for the comments.  I should have avoided the `.SD`.

Comment: thank you guys for this discussion, I learned a lot from it. Just a little question: I tried to shorten the code a little bit, and instead of `mydata[[j]][mydata$molclass=='negative']` I put `mydata[molclass=='negative'][[j]]`. The output is the same, but I am just curious if those two are absolutely equivalent (by internal implementation, or by speed of execution, etc).

Comment: @VasilyA If the dataset is not attached or there is no `molclass` object in the global environment, I get `Error in mean(mydata[[j]][molclass == "negative"]) : 
  object 'molclass' not found`

Comment: @akrun, I use it in different order: `mydata[molclass=='negative'][[j]]`, not `mydata[[j]][molclass == "negative"]`

Comment: @VasilyA Here we are getting the `[.data.table`.  As we discussed in the comments, this may be a bit slower (not sure)