# modify values of multiple columns in a table

Tags: r, data.table

So, here is my sample data:

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- fread(
"sample,neg1,neg2,neg3,gen1,gen2
sample1,   0,   1,   2,  30, 60
sample2,   1,   0,   1,  15, 30
sample3,   2,   1,   0,  10, 20
")
```

and in each row I want to subtract background (`mean` of "neg" columns). My current code is the following:

```
negatives <- names(mydata)[grep("^neg", names(mydata))] # "neg1" "neg2" "neg3"
mydata[, names(mydata)[-1]:={
  bg <- mean(unlist(.SD[, negatives, with=F]));
  .SD - as.integer(bg);
}, with=F, by=sample]

# mydata
#    sample neg1 neg2 neg3 gen1 gen2
#1: sample1   -1    0    1   29   59
#2: sample2    1    0    1   15   30
#3: sample3    1    0   -1    9   19
```

it does the job, but works quite slow on my real bigger table - I assume, it's because of using `.SD`. Is there better way to do this task? using `set` somehow?

(this question is very similar to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597878/background-subtraction-in-a-table): the source data is in another form here, so I could not find the way to apply the same solution with `set`, hope it will not be considered a duplicate).

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: I came up with a two step solution.  You can check if it is faster wrt to your solution `mydata1 <-  mydata[ , V1:=list(as.integer(rowMeans(.SD))), .SDcols=indx];
mydata1[, names(mydata1)[-c(1,7)]:= .SD-mydata1[['V1']], .SDcols=2:6][,V1:=NULL][]`

Comment: Another option would to get the `rowMeans` on the selected columns separately and then use `set` to update all the columns.  I updated the solution

Comment: both solutions work correctly and faster than mine! thanks a lot!

Comment: Your initial paragraph in parentheses would be better as a comment. That's what I usually do when I have something meta to say about my question. SO questions should be useful to folks who come across them in the future and that paragraph is "noise" distracting from the content.

Comment: thanks for pointing, I modified it and moved to the end (it would look strange as a 4th comment here; in addition, I think that previous question I am linking to may also be useful for someone).

Comment: How about melting the whole thing (I mean converting your data frame into a 'long' format using `melt` from `reshape2` or `gather` from `tidyr`), after which the problem becomes trivial?

Comment: well, it's not so obvious for me - if you can add the code as a separate answer, I will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the `rowMeans` of the "neg", columns ("val"), then update all the columns (subtracting from "val") of the dataset except the 1st using `set`.

```
 indx <- grep('^neg', names(mydata))
 val <- as.integer(rowMeans(mydata[, ..indx]))
 for(j in 2:ncol(mydata)){
  set(mydata, i=NULL, j=j, value=mydata[[j]]-val)
 }

 mydata
 #    sample neg1 neg2 neg3 gen1 gen2
 #1: sample1   -1    0    1   29   59
 #2: sample2    1    0    1   15   30
 #3: sample3    1    0   -1    9   19
```